# How to delete a search Index itself

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

Search Index has a method to delete a document.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/indexclass (Python)
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/Index (java)

But how to delete Index itself?

Empty Index was listed at the Text Search Panel in the Admin Console.

but no button to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have tagged `gae-search` I assume your question refers to an index of the Search API (i.e. full text search service, not NDB/HRD datastore index).

Currently you can only [delete the documents](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search#Python_Deleting_documents_from_an_index) in an index, but you can't delete the index itself, e.g. issue [8235](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8235&q=delete%20search%20index&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) and [8490](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8490&q=delete%20search%20index&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log). This restriction of Search API applies to all languages supported in Google App Engine.

The `vacuum_indexes` prompts you only for indices in datastore, but I miss something like this for the search service too.

Answer (score 2):

When running a local dev environment with version 1.9.x (and possibly earlier), you can pass this argument to dev_appserver.py to simply clear ALL of them regardless of whether there are documents in them:

```
--clear_search_indexes [CLEAR_SEARCH_INDEXES]
```

It doesn't look like there's a way to clear an individual index yet though based on the issue statuses posted above by Ani.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a running version? I tried deleting the version entirely from the admin console, but when I deployed it again (with the same version id) the index was still there.